Optimizing my crystal radio
I built a crystal radio, it looks like this: 

I used this schematic:

https://imgur.com/4YCyTwv
I found a video online about it:
3D Printed Radio | No Batteries
Sadly I am not as lucky, because I live in Europe (in Slovenia) and I don't have any local AM station around me (fortunately, also no QRM around).
For now we still have 4 MW stations in Slovenia:

1 transmitter at Nemčavci carying (Murski val on 648 kHz which broadcasts with 10 kW and Radio station for Hungarians, broadcasting on 558 kHz with 25 kW)
Second transmitter at Beli križ, carying Radio Koper on 549khz and Radio Capodistria on 1170 kHz both use 15kW TX) Beli križ is about 110 km away (to South West) While Nemčavci is is about 150 km away (North East)

While at night I do hear more stations (with my DSP radios) but their signal is again not powerful.
So my little crystal radio sadly does not pick up anything useful (I can pick up QRM from my Plazma TV).
I have Germanium diode.
30m long antenna
And also The longest wire I have is this solid core which was used as electric fence (it's disconnected for years now), it's isolated from ground with ceramic insulators.


Not sure about its length, but it should be couple 100 meters long if not even a kilometer (it's all around the fence).



Would really like to use it, since it's already set up on high place, and I heard, the longer wire, the better signal.
I have 3200 Ω headphones.
I have CBB28 (internet says its 0.0047uF) capacitor at hand.
So now I will build another one from wood, but this time I will try to optimize everything I can.
I have 24 AWG (about 0.5mm) of magnet wire.
How do I create the right coil for MW band? How do I know the outer diameter of it and how many turns it has to have?
I am trying to optimize for maximum sensitivity, so I could at least pick up something.

https://rabjohn.ca/data/documents/High-Performance-Crystal-Radios-for-electroics-club_v2.pdf

Your antenna wire isn't as useful as you might think. Being mere centimeters away from the grounded chain-link fence, it can only pick up a tiny fraction of the available E-field signal. You need a wire that's much higher up in the air, and away from other conductive objects.

Make the Antenna wire as high and as long as possible ,then improve the grounding with multiple rods and lots of shallow ground radials .Now look at your coil .Keep the inductance about the same to preserve tuning range .Bigger is better which means of course fewer turns heavier wire .This means higher unloaded Q so less losses .You could consider litz wire for high Q .If size matters then look at a low loss ferrite core with a gap to get the inductance .An E65 planer is maybe a bit of overkill but from experience you can get high Q .
